# TCP connect() call to device on local network very slow

Tags: linux, debian, tcp

I am running a local DHCP server using isc-dhcp-server on Debian linux, address 10.0.0.1.
I have a relay on 10.0.0.99, to which a pulse is sent every 4 seconds or so via an HTTP request.

The pseudo-code works as follows:

```
while (1) {
    get curr_time
    if ((webrelay->socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) <= 0) {
        log_perror(MYNAME "socket invalid for webrelay %i", webrelay->webrelay_id);
        usleep(4000 * 1000);
        continue;
     }
    if ((flags = fcntl(webrelay->socket, F_GETFL, 0)) == -1) 
        log_error("fcntl fail for webrelay");
    else
        fcntl(webrelay->socket, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    if (setsockopt(webrelay->socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &one, sizeof(one)) < 0) 
            perror("setsockopt fail for webrelay");

    relay_socket.sin_family = AF_INET;
    relay_socket.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)webrelay->net_port);
    relay_socket.sin_addr.s_addr = webrelay->net_address.s_addr;
    if (connect(webrelay->socket, (const struct sockaddr*)&relay_socket, sizeof(relay_socket)) < 0) {
        switch (errno) {
        case EINPROGRESS:
            while (1) {
                if time_now - curr_time > 4 seconds, 
                    print "connect slow", close socket and next iteration of for loop
                else 
                    fds[0].fd = webrelay->socket;
                    fds[0].events = POLLIN | POLLOUT;
                    fds[0].revents = 0;
                    if (poll(fds, sizeof(fds) / sizeof(fds[0]), 1) < 0) {
                        log "connect fail", close socket and next iteration of for loop
                    }
                    if (fds[0].revents & (POLLIN | POLLOUT))
                        break;
        case OTHER_ERROR_HANDLING:
            these cases never get called
        }
    }
    send(webrelay->socket, state_xml, sizeof(state_xml), MSG_DONTWAIT) //and perform error checks
    shutdown(webrelay->socket, SHUT_RDWR);
    close(webrelay->socket);
    webrelay->socket = 0; 
    //wait short amount and to next iteration
}
```

Unfortunately, after leaving the computer on for multiple days, I keep getting those EINPROGRESS errors from the connect(), meaning it is taking multiple seconds to connect(). If I set the connection to the normal blocking mode, I will instead get timeout errors on the connect() call. As a result, the relay turns off because it is taking very long to connect, and the last pulse expires before a new one can be sent.

All other network function calls work seamlessly, and tshark doesn't show any abnormal packets on that ethernet interface as far as I can tell (see https://pastebin.com/kTfwc5sr, where 10.0.0.100 is just another unrelated device).

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of the connect() call?

Comment: All can be seen is that the SYN is retransmitted multiple times since no SYN+ACK is received. The reason for this is outside of your code and likely outside of your system. Do a packet capture on the peer (10.0.0.99) to find out if the SYN from 10.0.0.1 get lost (and thus not get answered with SYN+ACK), if the SYN+ACK are generated but get lost or if the SYN+ACK do not get generated. Depending on this the problem is somewhere between client and server (packets get lost) or at the server (SYN+ACK does not get generated immediately).

Comment: You're getting EINGPROGRESS if you leave the connect blocking, but timeouts if you make it non-blocking? That sounds backwards.

Comment: @Kaz Yes my bad I mixed them up. Updated.